# AngularJs - facing an issue when using ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing an issue with using `ng-init` and assign it model inside my html.

The following code works fine. The following code is for Add/Edit functionality. For example, when row is is opened in `Edit` mode than it persist existing value and shows it in `textbox`.

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="title == 'Add Student'">
    <input type="text" name="name"placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="registration.Student.FirstName" maxlength="50">
    </div>

    <div ng-if="title == 'Edit Student'">
    <input type="text" name="name"placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="student.Student.FirstName" maxlength="50">
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the following code which is short version of above code does not work. I mean when the row is opened in edit mode it shows text field but does not show existing value (first name) in it. **Why?**

```
<div ng-init="model = (title == 'Add Student' ? registration.Student : student.Student)">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="model.FirstName" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

Please suggest whether ng-init can't be used in this way or some issue in my code?

thanks

**Controller**

```
var currentState = $state.current.name;
    if if (currentState == "Add")
    {
        $scope.registration = {
        Student: {
        FirstName: '',
    }
        var _init = function () {
    }
        $scope.title = " Add Student";
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.student= {};
        $scope.student= response[0];
        var _init = function () {
        $scope.title = " Edit Student";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Angular 1.1.5 added a ternary operator`, which version are you using?

Comment: I am initializing model with either  registration.Student Or student.Student based on condition title == 'Add Student' ... and than use model.FirstName in my input text box.

Comment: Could you please create plunker?

Comment: @immirza are you sure you already have values `registration.Student` & `student.Student` at the start of controller or this value are fetched from ajax?

Comment: it works fine...include your controller code,may be error in controller ccode

Comment: @ pankajparkar, yes i am sure. Becuase it is working with 1st code snippet of my question. It is only not working for 2nd code snippet of my question. Both are at same place.. i just commented 1st code snippet. registration.Student & student.Student are coming from angular controller.

Comment: @immirza check mine answer

Comment: @immirza what do you mean by `response[0]` in your controller code?

Comment: @ pankajparkar, its just a response from server. it works fine.

Comment: that means you are showing input `div` regardless of data has been loaded or not correct?

Comment: Yes, regardless of data loaded or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `ng-init` block is wrong currently it is returning `true` or `false`, you are messing with brackets.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-init="model = (title == 'Add Student') ? registration.Student : student.Student">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="model.FirstName" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

**Update**

In your current case you `ng-init` is getting executed while element rendered on the DOM, at that instance on time `registration.Student` & `student.Student` doesn't have any value. Evaluation of `ng-init` setting null object to the `model` student. I'd suggest you do set model value from the controller logic that would be more safer.

**Code**

```
var currentState = $state.current.name;
    if (currentState == "Add")
    {
        $scope.registration = {
        Student: {
        FirstName: '',
    }
        var _init = function () {
    }
        $scope.title = " Add Student";
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.student= {};
        $scope.student= response[0];
        var _init = function () {
        $scope.title = " Edit Student";
    }
    //shifted logic in controller
    $scope.model = (title == 'Add Student' ? registration.Student : student.Student);

}
```

**Markup**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Student Name" 
     data-ng-model="model.FirstName" maxlength="50"/>
</div>
```

Other way you could add one more flag like `loadedData` which will says that ajax response has been fetched & `registration.Student` & `student.Student` values are available in the scope.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-if="loadedData">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="model.FirstName" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

**Code**

```
var currentState = $state.current.name;
    if (currentState == "Add")
    {
        $scope.registration = {
        Student: {
        FirstName: '',
    }
        var _init = function () {
    }
        $scope.title = " Add Student";
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.student= {};
        $scope.student= response[0];
        var _init = function () {
        $scope.title = " Edit Student";
    }
    //set flag
    $scope.loadedData = true;

}
```

Comment: ng init can be used in `ng-init="model = (title == 'Add Student' ? registration.Student : student.Student")` way also

Comment: @visakhsujathan then model value would be either true or false, read my answer..that is where OP was wrong

Comment: @pankajparkar, unfortunately it did not workout for me. I used the same way you mentioned. corrected brackets but still no value shows.

Comment: @immirza then I'm pretty sure your data is loading from ajax or somewhere then your html could be `<div ng-if="registration.Student && student.Student" ng-init="model = (title == 'Add Student') ? registration.Student : student.Student">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="model.FirstName" maxlength="50">
</div>`

Comment: @visakh sujathan, my controller code is too big.... just an idea i am using $scope.title = "Register" in my _init() call. so, when Add button is clicked the calls go to controller where i have If check on state name. If it is Add than _Init() is called for Register and title is set to "Register" .. If it is Edit than _init() is called for Edit and $scope.title = "Manage User". Did u get it?

Comment: @visakhsujathan i don't understand, how can this work..that will any case will set true or false object, but you need to set an object to model..

Comment: @immirza whether the data is in`$scope.registration={
            "Student":{
                "FirstName":"name"
            }
        };
        $scope.student={
            "Student":{
                "FirstName":"name"
            }
        };` form

Comment: @immirza could i know how are we setting `registration.Student` & `student.Student` by controller code..could you add it in question

Comment: @pankajparkar, i have added. plz have look.